# "Русло восстановили, и река потекла(,) как прежде." Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, сказуемые, как, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

Согласно правилу, сравнительный оборот «как (и) прежде» **обособляются** (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот **входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу**). Является ли данное предложение исключением? То есть можно ли считать **потекла как прежде** единым сказуемым или говорить о тесной связи этих слов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полагаю, здесь нужно опираться на контекст.

Запятая будет ставиться в том случае, если без "как прежде" смысл фразы будет искажён. То есть, убирая "как прежде", мы получаем новое по содержанию,  не соответствующее авторскому замыслу значение. "Русло восстановили, и река потекла". А до этого она не текла? Вероятно, текла, но не так, как прежде. То есть, без "как прежде" предложение невозможно. Тогда и запятая опускается, потому что имеется тесная связь со сказуемым.
Если же река вообще не текла до восстановления русла, то мы можем сказать: "Русло восстановили, и река потекла", и эта фраза изложит нашу мысль полностью, а все сравнения и уточнения уже будут отделяться запятой.
Так что смотрите на контекст и, исходя из него, ставьте или не ставьте запятую по этому принципу.

Собственно, в правиле тоже указаны подобные примеры, опираясь на которые, можно прийти к этому же выводу. "Она вышла из больницы, но работать как раньше уже не могла." Это значит, что работать она могла, так что фраза через запятую исказила бы смысл. Она не могла именно работать именно как прежде.

Если же контекста нет, и имеется голая фраза, то запятую ставить не стоит. Она потребуется при наличии дополнительных слов: "сильно, как прежде", "как прежде, по правому берегу" и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А если контекст такой. Река потекла по-старому, по-прежнему. Река потекла так, как текла и раньше, как и всегда текла. Нужна ли запятая? И чем становится сочетание "как прежде", если не выделяется запятыми? Наречием или оно остается сравнительным оборотом?

Comment: Такая трактовка была бы противоречива: "текла всё время, а в какой-то момент потекла(,) как прежде" по смыслу указывает на изменение свойств "течения". Поэтому вариант с запятой может соответствовать только тому, что во время работ по руслу река не текла (отвели в сторону и т. п.).

Comment: Река не может не течь. Если ей загородить дорогу, тогда она потечет "в сторону".

Comment: Может: с точки зрения присутствующих вблизи осушённого для работ русла (местных жителей и работников) нет течения или реки.

Answer (score 1):

**Русло восстановили, и река потекла как преждЕ** (по прежнему руслу).

Оборот не обособляется, нет паузы, ударение падает на оборот.

Оборот входит в основное содержание предложения: "река потекла" не имеет законченного смысла (а раньше что с ней было, она же не могла совсем не течь.)